# sympy matrix to explicit sum and back (to matrix notation)

Tags: matrix, sympy, simplification

I am working in sympy with symbolic matrices.

Once made explicit I can not return to implicit representations.

I tried to work something out with the pair of `.as_explicit()` and `MatrixExpr.from_index_summation(expr)`

But the latter seems to expect an explicit sigma notation sum, not a sum of indexed elements.

As a minimal working example here is my approach on matrix multiplication:

```
A = MatrixSymbol('A',3,4)
B = MatrixSymbol('B',4,3)
Matrix_Notation = A * B
Expanded = (A * B).as_explicit()
FromSummation = MatrixExpr.from_index_summation(Expanded)
```

Here we can see, that `FromSummation` is still the same as `Expanded`

I suppose that the `Expanded` expression should be converted to sigma sums such that `.from_index_summation` can be expected to work. But how can this be done?

Comment: Why go back instead of using `Matrix_Notation`?